# Simple testable PIC16F1703 code?

Tags: assembly, pic

I have high difficulty to make a PIC16F1703 to work, I would like to ensure the code sample I am using is correct.

It is supposed to be one of the simplest example possible, and make all the pin to output VDD, so I may test it with a voltmeter/LED.

```
        processor   16F1703
        radix       dec
        include     p16f1703.inc
        errorlevel  -302

; reset vector
        org H'00'
        goto    init

; interrupt vector
        org H'04'
init    NOP
        BANKSEL PORTA
        CLRF    PORTA
        BANKSEL PORTC
        CLRF    PORTC
        BANKSEL LATA
        CLRF    LATA
        BANKSEL LATC
        CLRF    LATC
        BANKSEL ANSELA
        CLRF    ANSELA
        BANKSEL ANSELC
        CLRF    ANSELC
        BANKSEL TRISA
        MOVLW   B'00111111'
        MOVWF   TRISA
        BANKSEL TRISC
        MOVLW   B'00111111'
        MOVWF   TRISC

loop    NOP
        goto    loop


        end
```

**Is this sample correct for a PIC16F1703 and maintaining all pin at VDD? If no, what is wrong?**

Comment: Have you tried some simulator? Simulators may have debugger facilities. Google for "PIC16F simulator" and see if they can help you.

Comment: @MargaretBloom: Unfortunately, I do not know about any pic simulator which support PIC16F170x family.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No tihis code isn't correct!

According to data sheet, if you set bits in TRISA and TRISB registers to 1 then all corresponding pins are configured as input.

By the way Microchip MPLAB support all PIC MCPUs simulations!

Check datasheet PIC16F1703 section I/O PORTS there is an example: EXAMPLE 11-1: INITIALIZING PORTA

Comment: You are right, I mixed TRISx and PORTx. I will also try the MPLAB simulator.